# How to implement recent search component based on container width and individual search text width?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

**I have a search component where I show recent searches at the bottom . How do I show all the recent searches based on the amount of parent div width and each search items width . **

So if the recent searches overflows the parent container then I want to show only those searches that are visible and others with one text (+ remaining) .

I tried it with useRef - parentRef and childRef and calculating the amount of items that are visible.
and using a state to store it after calculation .

But the when I use that state to slice while mapping it in the jsx , the logic doesn't work .

sandbox link - [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-dubinsky-t854km?file=/src/RecentSearch.js)

```
const calculateWidth = () => {
      if (parentRef.current && itemsRef.current) {
        const parentWidth = parentRef.current.clientWidth - 48;
        const childWidth = itemsRef.current.clientWidth;
        const textsElements = Array.from(itemsRef.current.children);
        let totalWidth = 0;
        let visibleSearchesCount = 0;

        console.log(parentWidth);

        for (let i = 0; i < textsElements.length; i++) {
          const textElement = textsElements[i];
          const { width } = textElement.getBoundingClientRect();
          console.log(textElement, 'textelement', width, 'width');
          totalWidth += width;
          if (totalWidth < parentWidth) {
            visibleSearchesCount++;
          }
        }
        console.log(
          totalWidth + 'totalWidth',
          visibleSearchesCount,
          'visibleSearchesCount'
        );
        setTotalWidth(totalWidth);
        setVisibleSearches(visibleSearchesCount - 1);
        // console.log(width, 'width');
      }
    };
```

RecentSearchComponent

```
return (
    <ComponentWrapper ref={containerRef}>
      <ComponentTitle>Recent: </ComponentTitle>
      <ResultsContainer ref={itemsRef}>
        {results.map((result, i) => {
          const { query } = result;
          return (
            <Result key={i}>
              <Value>{query}</Value>
            </Result>
          );
        })}
        {results.length > visibleSearches && (
          <Result>
            <Value>+{results.length - visibleSearches}</Value>
          </Result>
        )}
      </ResultsContainer>
    </ComponentWrapper>
  );
```

I called this function and used it in a useEffect with the results = [] as the dependency . On first page load it doesn't work, but then you make some change in code and save, it works correctly . :)
`

sandbox link - [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-dubinsky-t854km?file=/src/RecentSearch.js)